# "How to implement a feature of searching text inside the .pdf and .word documents in django application"

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-rest-framework, django-haystack

I am building a web app collection of documents in .pdf and .word format and want to implement search functionality to find words inside the documents. What would be the easiest way to implement it?

I have searched and came across of integrating Elastic Search + Haystack  into my app here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xr1b39XMtBQ&t=476s, but seems could not find exactly what I want to do. Any help appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/63021409/11114999 except with a different stack.